# When computed method changes doesn't update

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have a component that has an icon that I want to show only if the method from getters returns true. That method returns true when a user logged in. I am using a computed property to track the changes but I have to reload the page so that computed method can be updated.

```
<template>
  <div class="icon" v-if="isUserLoged" >
     <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  computed: {
    isUserLoged() {
      return this.$store.getters.isUserLoged;
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

```
getters:{
  isUserLoged(state){
   return state.auth_token !== null
  },
}
```

```
actions:{
    login({commit},payload){
      return axios.post("/users/login",payload)
      .then(data => {
        commit('SET_TOKEN',data.data.auth_token)  
      })
      .catch(error => {
        return error.response
      })
    },
},
mutations:{
  SET_TOKEN(state,data){
      state.auth_token = data
    },
}
```

Token is set when login api is called on actions section

Comment: Can you show your related actions/mutations. I feel you may be falling fowl of some of Vuex's mutation reactivity rules: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/mutations.html#mutations-follow-vue-s-reactivity-rules

Comment: Have you defined an initial default state in your store with the properties you are going to be using?

Comment: Yes for this case is auth_token:null

Comment: Instead of `state.auth_token = data` inside your `SET_TOKEN` mutation, try the following: `Vue.set(stats, 'auth_token', data)` or `this._vm.$set(stats, 'auth_token', data)` depending on your setup.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. What is weird is that I use this method on a computed property in another component and it works just fine. But on this component, it doesn't. If I go and save the project then it works. I think it has to do something with loading the component again?